# Configuring git for Visual Studio to push to the magic gerrit branch

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, gerrit

I'm working with Visual Studio and Gerrit. I'm trying to set up my git config such that the default push would be to the magic Gerrit branch refs/for/master, and pull will be as normal. I have changed my git config to this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ...
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    push = refs/heads/*:refs/for/*
```

but the push is still made to `refs/heads/master`.

Also tried to change

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/for/master
```

but VS keeps deleting this section from the config.

What is the correct way?

Note I'm not trying to integrate gerrit in VS, I'm just trying to make VS push to the correct branch.

Comment: I pinged the author of the VS Git tools. Not sure why it's altering or disrespecting the setting.

Comment: Have you received any answer at the end on this?

Comment: @Giordano no, used git command line tools in the end.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1. Install ["vscode-commandbar"](https://github.com/ppatotski/vscode-commandbar) extension
2. Configure a new status bar command button for running the git command:

```
{
    "skipTerminateQuickPick": true,
    "skipSwitchToOutput": false,
    "skipErrorMessage": true,
    "commands": [
        {
            "text": "$(repo-push) Gerrit Push",
            "tooltip": "Run command: \"git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master\"",
            "color": "yellow",
            "command": "git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master",
            "alignment": "left",
            "skipTerminateQuickPick": false,
            "priority": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

3. Restart VScode and enable the new button if necessary)

Result:
[Status bar with the new button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdJgn.png)

Comment: Alas VS != VSCode.

Comment: Do you know how to make 'master' in that command refer to the currently checked out branch in the repository?